# Selenium can't find search element inside form

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to use selenium to perform searches in lexisnexis and I can't get it to find the search box. 
I've tried find_element_by using all possible attributes and I only get the "NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: " error every time. 
[See screenshot of the inspection tab -- the highlighted part is the element I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgtlR.png)

My code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

searchTerms = r'something'
url = r'https://www.lexisnexis.com/uk/legal/news' # this is the page after login - not including the code for login here.

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = path_to_chromedriver)
browser.get(url)
```

I tried everything:

```
browser.find_element_by_id('search-query')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="search-query"]')
browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/header/div/form/div[2]/input')
```

etc..
Nothing works. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Could be possible your site is taking to long to load , in such cases you can use waits to avoid synchronization issue.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
inputBox = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='search-query']")))
```

**Note** : Add below imports to your solution

```
 from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
 from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
 from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```